# NeoMutt: How to Edit To/Subject/CC Fields in Vim?

Tags: vim, mutt

When I'm composing mail in mutt the default keybindings for editing fields such as `to`,`subject`, and `cc` is to open a one-line input at the bottom of the window.

However, if I've made a mistake, or am trying to edit a long list of emails, this single line editor is not useful.

So, while I like having this as the default behaviour, I would like to know how I can also open and edit these fields in a vim window.

Answer (score 4):

Set this inside your `.muttrc` and you are able to edit the mail header like `From:`, `To:`, `Cc:`, `Bcc:`, `Subject:` and so on while editing the message.

```
set edit_headers = yes`
```

Comment: Okay great! I'll try this out for a bit, but initially it seems a bit annoying to have these at the top of every message. Is there a way to have this optional? So the default behaviour is, as before, `edit_headers = 'no'` and then I can activate it with a key as needed.

Comment: Also, this has the pretty annoying effect where I still have to fill out "To" and "Subject" fields in the original one-line editor before I'm brought into the vim editor.

Comment: @Jesse you may want `set autoedit = yes` to skip the initial send menu

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following mappings to have `Ctrl` open Vim:

```html
macro index,pager \Cr "<enter-command>set edit_headers = yes<enter><reply>"
macro index,pager \CR "<enter-command>set edit_headers = yes<enter><group-reply>"
macro index,pager \CL "<enter-command>set edit_headers = yes<enter><list-reply>"
# macro index,pager \Cm "<enter-command>set edit_headers = yes<enter><enter-command>set autoedit = yes<enter><mail>"
```

I've commented out the last one messed with my mapping to open a message from the index in Vim (`l` does a preview):

```html
macro index l "<enter-command>set pager=<enter><enter-command>set pager_index_lines=20<enter><display-message>"
macro index <Return> "<enter-command>set pager=nvim<enter><enter-command>unset prompt_after<enter><display-message>"
```

I've also tweaked the `init.vim` to streamline the process of adding addresses a bit with:

```
" abook syntax highlighting
Plug 'paniash/abook.vim', {  'branch': 'main'}
" open abook addressbook in a horizontal split
nnoremap <leader>ca <C-w>s:e ~/.abook/addressbook<CR>
" paste and format abook entry in header
nnoremap <leader>ci pdddws"<Esc>A"<Esc>j0dws<<Esc>A><Esc>kJkJjddk$
```

So now you can `<leader>ca` to open abook's addressbook in a horizontal split, search for the email you want, copy the whole entry with `yap` and paste and format it in the message header using `<leader>ci`.